# Deferred Segment Creation feature not enabled (ORA-00439)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I have `.sql` script file with DDL for more than 60 tables. I am trying to copy-paste the script into SQL Developer, connected to a database which is "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production".

Sample DDL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE UserName."Table_Name" 
   (    "Col1" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "Col2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "Col3" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation
00439. 00000 -  "feature not enabled: %s"
*Cause:    The specified feature is not enabled.
*Action:   Do not attempt to use this feature.
```

If I remove `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED` in the DDL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE UserName."Table_Name" 
   (    "Col1" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "Col2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "Col3" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   ) 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
```

This works. But I can't manually remove that in  each and every table script.

If I have `.dmp` dump file then the following syntax will also solve the issue; on the source instance:

```
EXPDP user/pwd dumpfile=somename.dmp directory=DATA_DUMP_DIR nologfile=Y version=10.2
```

and on the target instance

```
IMPDP user/pwd dumpfile=somename.dmp directory=DATA_DUMP_DIR nologfile=Y version=10.2
```

But I don't have a `.dmp` file, I only have a `.sql` file.

Which is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Where is your `.sql` file coming from, and if you can't generate it without the clause XE doesn't support, why can't you edit out the segment creation clause? That seems like a fairly trivial find/replace?

Comment: Thanks for the Edit/reply.


*.sql file is in the local system where I have DB installed. Find/Replace will work fine that is what I have done right now. But what do you mean by "without clause XE doesn't support" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deferred segment creation option [is not available in Oracle 11g Express Edition (XE)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC116), which is what you are using. It's only [available in Enterprise Edition (EE)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/editions.htm#DBLIC116).

If you don't want to do an export/import and can only use the supplied script file you already have, your only option is to find and remove all instances of the `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED` clause.

Any text edit can do that of course, and SQL Developer [has its own find/replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55747_01/appdev.41/e55591/dialogs.htm#RPTUG41762) in the SQL Worksheet window.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE` in place of `SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED`