# Oracle 11g downgrade from Enetrprise to Standard

Tags: oracle, migrate, impdp, expdp

I need to export a database from 11.1g Enterprise and import into 11.2g Standard but have been having some trouble importing the DMP file.

I have exported using the usual EXPDP but when I IMPDP I get lots of errors like:

```
ORA-01917: user or role 'XXX' does not exist
```

and

```
[exec] ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"USER"."TABLE" failed to create with error:
[exec] ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Deferred Segment Creation
```

Are there specific parameters I need to include in my EXPDP and/or IMPDP to successfully migrate the database?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941314/deferred-segment-creation-feature-not-enabled-ora-00439

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deferred Segment Creation feature not enabled (ORA-00439)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941314/deferred-segment-creation-feature-not-enabled-ora-00439)

Comment: I downgraded 14 databases from Enterprise to Standard edition. Even though IMPDP will create accounts with quotas, I had issues with this and ended up pre-creating all of the table spaces and all of the users I was importing. I used TOAD to generate the user scripts. After doing this, the import went without issue, except for the errors that the user id's already exist.